# Libgdx: How to rotate a button on main menu

Tags: java, android, libgdx

How to keep rotating a button on main menu screen around its center, here's the code for the button

```
final ImageButton btnSett=UIFactory.createButton(txtrSettings);
btnSett.setScale(1,1);
btnSett.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/ 2,0.f, Align.center);
stage.addActor(btnSett);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try applying an `Action` to the button.

For example, to make the `Button` rotate once apply a *rotate* action:

```
btnSett.addAction(Actions.rotateBy(360, 1));
```

This will rotate `btnSett` once over one second.
To make something continuously rotate you can apply a *repeated* action, and actions can also be in sequence, for example;

```
btnSett.addAction(Actions.repeat(RepeatActions.FOREVER, 
                  Actions.sequence(
                     Actions.rotateBy(360, 1), // First, rotate once   
                     Actions.rotateTo(0));     // Then, instantly set the rotation to 0 so that the previous action makes sense again.
```

You'll also need to set the *origin* of the `Button` to it's center first;

```
btnSett.setOrigin(btnSett.getWidth() / 2, btnSett.getHeight() / 2);
```

To make the actions code look cleaner consider making static imports of the methods in `Actions`, that way the code can look more like;

```
btnSett.addAction(repeat(RepeatActions.FOREVER, 
                         sequence(rotateBy(360, 1), 
                                  rotateTo(0));
```